# Template redirect is_tax() not working

Tags: templates, redirect

I'm trying to do a template redirect in my wordpress but with partial success

```
  function ahaali_qa_theme_redirect(){
    global $wp;
    $plugindir = dirname(__FILE__);

    if(is_archive()){
        $tname = 'archive-question.php';
        if(file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH.'/'.$tname)){
            $returntemplate = TEMPLATEPATH.'/'.$tname;
        }else{
            $returntemplate = $plugindir.'/default-template/'.$tname;
        }
        ahaali_do_theme_redirect($returntemplate);
    }elseif(is_single()){
        $tname = 'single-question.php';
        if(file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH.'/'.$tname)){
            $returntemplate = TEMPLATEPATH.'/'.$tname;
        }else{
            $returntemplate = $plugindir.'/default-template/'.$tname;
        }
        ahaali_do_theme_redirect($returntemplate);
    }elseif(is_archive() && is_tax('question_category')){
        $tname = 'taxonomy-question_category.php';
        if(file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH.'/'.$tname)){
            $returntemplate = TEMPLATEPATH.'/'.$tname;
        }else{
            $returntemplate = $plugindir.'/default-template/'.$tname;
        }
        ahaali_do_theme_redirect($returntemplate);
    }
}
```

everything works except the is_tax() , can somebody explain me how to do this or what I'm doing wrong ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is just a simple php syntax issue- anything that meets the conditions `is_archive() && is_tax('question_category')` will also return true for the first `if(is_archive())`, so you're code is never reaching that test.

Comment: Also, [`is_tax()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_taxonomy) is deprecated as of 3.0.  You should be using [`taxonomy_exists()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/taxonomy_exists) instead.

Comment: is_tax() is not deprecated. What is deprecated is is_taxonomy() (in fact, you've actually linked to this function).