# is_tax not working for custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, templates, taxonomy, pluggable

I am trying to over-ride a custom taxonomy file from my plugin. Actually, I have 2 custom taxonomies: **destination** & **activities**. I have successfully over-ridden the taxonomy template for activities but for destination `is_tax()` function is not working. That is why I am unable to over-ride the taxonomy template for destination. Everything including slug is absolutely correct. Tried this as well: [Template redirect is_tax() not working](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55445/template-redirect-is-tax-not-working?rq=1) On body tag, this is the class that is displayed on failed state: *hfeed image-filters-enabled*

Below is my function:

```
function abc( $template_path ) {
    if( is_tax( 'destination' ) )
    {
        $template_path = locate_template( array( 'taxonomy-destination.php' ) );

        // LOOK IN MAIN PLUGIN
        if( !$template_path )
        {
            $template_path = WP_TRAVEL_ENGINE_TEMPLATE_PATH . '/taxonomy-destination.php';
        }

        // OVER-RIDE FROM CURRENT PLUGIN
        if( $template_path )
        {
            $template_path = WP_TRAVEL_ENGINE_VENDOR_BASE_PATH . '/public/vendor-templates/page-templates/taxonomy-destination.php';
        }
        return $template_path;
    }
    if( is_tax( 'activities' ) )
    {
        $template_path = locate_template( array( 'taxonomy-activities.php' ) );

        // LOOK IN MAIN PLUGIN
        if( !$template_path )
        {
            $template_path = WP_TRAVEL_ENGINE_TEMPLATE_PATH . '/taxonomy-activities.php';
        }

        // OVER-RIDE FROM CURRENT PLUGIN
        if( $template_path )
        {
            $template_path = WP_TRAVEL_ENGINE_VENDOR_BASE_PATH . '/public/vendor-templates/page-templates/taxonomy-activities.php';
        }
        return $template_path;
    }
    return $template_path;
}
add_filter( 'template_include','abc' );
```

This is how taxonomy is registered:

```
$labels = array(
            'name'              => _x( 'Destinations', 'taxonomy general name', 'wp-travel-engine' ),
            'singular_name'     => _x( 'Destinations', 'taxonomy singular name', 'wp-travel-engine' ),
            'search_items'      => __( 'Search Destinations', 'wp-travel-engine' ),
            'all_items'         => __( 'All Destinations', 'wp-travel-engine' ),
            'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Destinations', 'wp-travel-engine' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Destinations', 'wp-travel-engine' ),
            'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Destinations', 'wp-travel-engine' ),
            'update_item'       => __( 'Update Destinations', 'wp-travel-engine' ),
            'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Destinations', 'wp-travel-engine' ),
            'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Destinations Name', 'wp-travel-engine' ),
            'menu_name'         => __( 'Destinations', 'wp-travel-engine' ),
        );

        $args = array(
            'hierarchical'      => true,
            'labels'            => $labels,
            'show_ui'           => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'destinations','hierarchical' => true ),
        );

        register_taxonomy( 'destination', array( 'trip' ), $args );
```

Any help would be more than appreciable.

Comment: And how is the taxonomy registered?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż Thanks for reply. I have added that in my question now.

Comment: Try adding `var_dump( get_queried_object() );` at the top of your `abc()` function and see if the result shows a valid term object. If not, you may need to add `wp_reset_query();` to reset the global `WP_Query` instance.

Comment: @SallyCJ Even if I add `die()` just after `function abc( $template_path ) {` , the function is not dying or its is not being called. Admin bar disappears as well when destination template is tried to access.

Comment: How are you attempting to view destinations? Are you certain the URL you're visiting is a taxonomy archive?

Comment: I would like to say sorry as well as thank you all for your help. I found the issue. It was my own mistake. A function was redirecting it somewhere else. I was trying to load *taxonomy-destination.php* for both: `abc.com/nepal` and `abc.com/destinations/nepal`. Can it be achieved?